# How to run database scripts on database shell in jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins

I added an Execute Shell build step in my jenkins job.

I need to start Oracle NoSQL shell and run some DDLs.

I wrote shell script.

```
#Run Client
java -jar /root/software/kv-3.2.5/lib/kvcli.jar -host localhost -port 5000

#Run scripts
plan remove-table -name PersonnelUni1To1FK -wait
plan remove-table -name HabitatUni1To1FK -wait
```

When I excecute the same from my teminal, it's working fine. Becuase after 1st command database shell started and remaining scripts ran over that shell.

**But build failed in Jenkins.**

Jenkins job console output:

> +java -jar /root/software/kv-3.2.5/lib/kvcli.jar -host localhost -port 5000
>
> kv-> + plan remove-table -name PersonnelUni1To1FK -wait
>   /tmp/hudson2708562803834708095.sh: line 17: plan: command not found
>
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Its trying to execute this all on my ubuntu shell not on database shell.

Answer (score 0):

`plan` is a command to be executed by the shell, right? The error message just says that it doesn't find the command, so the problem could be the setting of the PATH variable. What happens if you specify the absolute path to `plan` in your shell script? Alternatively, make sure that the PATH variable on Jenkins is correct.

Comment: `plan remove-table -name PersonnelUni1To1FK -wait` command runs on Oracle NoSQL shell not my Os shell

Comment: If I  fire `plan remove-table -name PersonnelUni1To1FK -wait` from my ubuntu terminal (shell) it says the same - "command not found"

Comment: But you are running `plan` from your shell script! Of course, the shell doesn't find the command. You need to feed it into the Oracle shell. For instance, if the Oracle shell reads the commands from STDIN, you need to redirect the commands into the STDIN of the Oracle shell.

Comment: Did you read the question correctly? I suggest read it again. Forget about `plan`. Just assume I am firing `create table abc (col1 int)` script on Oracle NoSQL shell.

Comment: Sorry, I understood your question that you want to know, why you get the `command not found` error, and what to do against it.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround,

I put all my scripts

```
plan remove-table -name PersonnelUni1To1FK -wait
plan remove-table -name HabitatUni1To1FK -wait

and many more...
```

in a file `/home/dev/ons/oracle-kv-db.script`

modified shell command for jenkins job

> `java -jar /root/software/kv-3.2.5/lib/kvcli.jar -host localhost -port 5000 < /home/dev/ons/oracle-kv-db.script`

Now it does not need database shell explicitly.